# Ajax call to use JSON data in UserControl.ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `usercontrol` in a `VisualWebPart` project.I want to have an ajax call to get a json data and use it in a Jquery plugin.
in simple `web applications` I use a webservice that returns JSON data and call It in my pages via Ajax,that sounds like I cant use webservices and even `Web Methods` in my .ascx control,so how can I call a method in my `UserControl` to get JSON data.

**EDIT:** I have this code and I want to do this in a `UserControl` ,too.
in `WebService`:

```
public class getTimeLineService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public String getJsonTimeLine()
    {
        List<TimeLine> list = new List<TimeLine> { new TimeLine { headline = "Vine", text = "<p>Vine Test</p>", startDate = "1391,12,12", endDate = "1392,1,27" }, new TimeLine { headline = "Sh*t Politicians Say", text = "<p>In true political fashion, his character rattles off common jargon heard from people running for office.</p>", startDate = "1392,1,26", endDate = "1392,1,27" } };
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        serializer.Serialize(list, sb);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and consume this `WebService` by ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getTimeLineService.asmx/getJsonTimeLine",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonDate = eval( data.d );
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a webmethod on the page and have the page's method pull from the server code. You could set a session value in the control and pull from that via your webmethod. As controls aren't pages, they're not actually serving anything, only being rendered.

As your using a static webmethod, you'll need to use HttpContext to get your session data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx

### Edit

Store your data from the user control in session:

`Session["MyData"] = myDataObj;`

You can access Session through your WebMethod this way:

```
var myRetrievedDataObj = HttpContext.Session["MyData"];
```

You can return serialized JSON from server objects and collections using the JavaScriptSerialzer class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

You then return that string to your AJAX call and you have your JSON data.